# Why is ElasticSearch putting strings in arrays?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm adding documents to an new index I created in elasticsearch (v7.15.1). I have a nested field I explicitly mapped:

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/newIndex/_mapping?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "properties": {
        "authors": {
            "type": "nested"
        }
    }
}
'
```

both properties under "authors" are strings. When adding documents to the index, each property under author is an array containing the string,

ex.

"author": ["John Smith"]

instead of

"author": "John Smith"

I've tried explicitly mapping the nested field as well as text, and I got the same result. Is there anyway to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need nested type. The nested field used for array of the Objects, not for array of the Strings. So you can use mapping like:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "authors": {
            "type": "keyword"
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you want to search only first name, you can use "type" : "text", or both of them with multifield
'

Comment: Sorry, I did not explain fully, the authors field is an array of objects. Each object represents a single author with multiple fields. It is the values of the author fields that are strings, but being uploaded as strings within arrays.

Comment: Am i understud right, that your mapping supposed to be like:
{
    "properties": {
        "authors": {
            "type": "nested",
   "properties":{
       "name" :{
        "type": "keyword"
    },
    "user" :{
        "type": "keyword"
    }
   }
        }
    }
}

Could you share the data example?